# Access field of subclassed object without casting

Tags: flutter, dart, inheritance, polymorphism

Given the following classes:

```dart
abstract class ParentState extends Equatable {
  const SomeState();
}

class SomeState extends ParentState {
  const SomeState({required this.someField});

  final String someField;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [someField];
}
```

I want to access `someField` if the current state is of type `SomeState` in my `mapEventToState` method, but the compiler doesn't allow that:

```dart
 @override
  Stream<ParentState> mapEventToState(
    ParentEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (state is SomeState) {
        print(state.someField); // Error: The getter 'someField' isn't defined for the type 'ParentState'.
    }
}
```

If I manually create a `ParentState` variable, however, it works as expected:

```dart
ParentState state = SomeState(someField: 'test');

if (state is SomeState) {
   print(state.someField); // Works.
}
```

Also, manually casting in `mapEventToState` works, but that shouldn't be required:

```dart
if (state is SomeState) {
    print((state as SomeState).someField); // Works.
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example with the error, it seems like `state` is a field in the surrounding class with an auto-generated getter and setter.

However from the perspective of the analyzer, it's possible for `state` to also be a getter function that allows the return of a *different* object each time the getter is called. So on the first call to the getter in the `if` statement the getter could return a `SomeState` object, but in the `if` body, the getter could return a completely different object without a `someField` getter.

To get around this problem, you just need to create a local copy of your variable within the function and use that copy instead of the class field:

```dart
@override
Stream<ParentState> mapEventToState(
  ParentEvent event,
) async* {
  final stateCopy = state;
  if (stateCopy is SomeState) {
      print(stateCopy.someField);
  }
}
```

Comment: `state` **is** a getter. It makes total sense that it doesn't work now. Thank you.